# Drying my trumpet out after playing

Tags: brass, trumpet

Whenever I practice on trumpet, after practicing there is a lot of water gathering inside the main tuning slide and thirs valve slide but also inside the valve caps so I have to unmount these valve caps and water comes out.

My question is if this is normal, and if I am doing right by doing all this everytime I practice, since I'm worried about my trumpet getting damaged in some way if I leave some of that water or moisture inside and I do not dry it out.

Will it dry out over time and, is emptying water inside slides enough? What do people (trumpeteers or brass players in general) do after playing the instrument for a while?

Comment: this is quite normal! I never cared for my instruments (except emptying the slides of course when bubbling! but now I have another euphonium I have to take care as the volves are locking  after a few days when not used  - if I don't dry them after playing. Anyway: It won't matter to take care to your instrument.
It

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is happening to your trumpet is completely normal. Your trumpet gets wet because, the warm air you is moist, and that moistness builds up into water. A wet trumpet isn't that harmful, its just that its harder to maintain each pitch. When my trumpet gets wet I use a very old cotton t-shirt to dry my trumpet, but you don't *have to* that; You can use other soft cloths to dry your trumpet. [Here](http://www.blackwellstrumpetbasics.com/wet-vs-dry/) is more about wet and dry trumpets.